# laravel database trascation manual rollback

Tags: laravel-9

database trascation manual rollback

I am trying to execute some queries which are dependant on each other, so what I want is if any error occurs then rollback all the queries inside transaction. what I've tried so far is

so when I execute this query It generates an error as SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'bill_id' doesn't have a default value, but it also creates a row on user_billings table. Can you please specify where I am wrong?